# unicode-math and braces scaling

Tags: luatex, scaling, braces, unicode-math, opentype

I am trying to create a minimal `lualatex` distribution, and hence try to eliminate as much non OTF fonts as possible (I try to get rid of the `.afm`, `.pfb`, `.map`, etc files to save space).

Everything is (almost) working for text, but I am hitting a bummer with maths and the `Kurier` font (and probably others I haven't tested yet).

The following MWE works perfectly with `kurier.sty` and the Type 1 fonts:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[light,math]{kurier}
\begin{document}
\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE with <code>kurier</code> and T1 fonts]

but the following with OTF fonts through `unicode-math` doesn't:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Kurier Light Regular}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit,\mathsfit]{Kurier Light Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup,\mathbfsfup]{Kurier Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit,\mathbfsfit]{Kurier Bold Italic}
\begin{document}
\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE with <code>unicode-math</code> and OTF fonts]

The parenthesis are correctly printed in `Kurier Light`, but not scaling with `\left` and `\right`.

So here are my 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to get them to scale with OTF fonts, or can this only be done with the Type1? How?
2. What things might I have forgotten to take care of, other than brace scaling?

Comment: Kurier Light is not a math font.

Comment: @egreg I know, but it does work work with `kurier.sty` and Type1 fonts as proven in the MWE.

Comment: As @egreg said, you need an OpenType Math font with unicode-math, but Kurier isn't.

Comment: @Khaled So how do you explain the first MWE?

Comment: @Xavier The first example uses Type1 fonts and would be printed the same with pdflatex

Comment: @Xavier, the first example is not using unicode-math, the second is.

Comment: @egreg Do you mean that `\left` and `\right` only work with Type1 fonts? Or that the Kurier font is missing some glyphs / non properly defined in its OTF form?

Comment: @Khaled I did notice that. That's the whole point of the question...

Comment: @Xavier `\left` and `\right` work with an OpenType font, but only if it has specific math tables and glyphs, which Kurier doesn't have.

Comment: @egreg So you implicitly mean that Kurier has those tables and glyphs in its Type1 version, but not its OpenType one? Because the MWE #1 generates a file that relies purely on Kurier from what my pdf reader tells me... Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Xavier The `kurier` package uses special math fonts with `pdflatex` and *not* OT fonts.

Comment: @egreg From the little I understand from `kurier.sty`, I don't see any special math font. I just see switches between different encodings (OMS/OMX for symbols). So either I am missing the special math font in there (my bad) and I also don't know why it doesn't show up in the list of fonts of the generated MWE pdf, or the OT version is missing those glyphs, or the glyphs are in the OT version but not properly used...

Comment: @Xavier pdflatex *doesn't* use OT fonts. *Never*. The switch to different encodings are exactly the choices of the special math fonts. And the *do* show up in the `.log` as `kurierl.pfb` and `kurierli.pfb`. They are Type1 fonts that contain also the math fonts and are reencoded using `ex-kurier.enc`, `sy-kurier.enc` and `rm-kurier.enc`. TeX is able to use the information provided in the proper `.tfm` files (which `unicode-math` can't use, of course).

Comment: @egreg I never talked about pdflatex --- the MWE explicitly mentions `% !TEX program = lualatex`. For `kurierl` and `kurierli`, those are not special math fonts, they are the standard `Kurier Light` fonts, upright and italic variants (if you look at `kurier.sty`, you will actually see that `kurierl` is set as `\rmdefault` when you use the `light` option). And those 2 fonts perfectly exist in OT format: `KurierLight-Regular.otf` and `KurierLight-Italic.otf`. So I still don't understand where things go wrong: in `unicode-math` (bug or my use of it) or in the `.otf` files themselves...

Comment: @Xavier If you don't load `fontspec`, LuaLaTeX behaves *exactly* like pdflatex.

Answer (score 9):

LuaTeX (and XeTeX) support two types of math fonts: the traditional TeX math fonts using TFM files and new OpenType math fonts.

With TFM fonts, all the parameters and other special properties that TeX needs for proper math typesetting are stored in the TFM files, and this is what is loaded by the `kurier` package so you get correct output with that.

OpenType math is a new extension to OpenType that stores all math parameters and properties in the OpenType fonts themselves, and that what you want to use with `unicode-math` package. OpenType version of Kurier does not provide an OpenType math font, only regular text fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just emailed the author of the Kurier font family to ask how much work it would be to include the math glyphes (I guess it's actually more about properties / font features, as the T1 glyphes can be embedded in OT theoretically) in the OT version. I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't load `fontspec`, the font management in LuaLaTeX is exactly the same as with `pdflatex`. The terminal output of the first run example with `lualatex` is

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011062107 (rev 4277) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./xavier.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
LuaTeX adaptation of babel <v3.8l-luatex-1.5> and hyphenation patterns for engl
ish, dumylang, nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/kurier.sty)
(./xavier.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/ot1kurierl.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/ot1kurierlm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/omlkurierl.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/omskurierl.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/omxkurierl.fd) [1{/usr/loc
al/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./xavier.aux) )

 237 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 33 glue_spec, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:13,3:21,4:33,5:5,6:22,7:2,9:22
{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/kurier/ex-kurier.enc}{/usr/
local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/kurier/sy-kurier.enc}{/usr/local/
texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/kurier/rm-kurier.enc}{/usr/local/texliv
e/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/kurier/mi-kurier.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2011
/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/nowacki/kurier/kurierl.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2011/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/nowacki/kurier/kurierli.pfb>
Output written on xavier.pdf (1 page, 35690 bytes).
Transcript written on xavier.log.
```

while with `pdflatex` is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./xavier.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nyn
orsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbia
nc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorb
ian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/kurier.sty)
(./xavier.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/ot1kurierl.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/ot1kurierlm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/omlkurierl.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/omskurierl.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/omxkurierl.fd) [1{/usr/loc
al/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./xavier.aux) )
{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/kurier/ex-kurier.enc}{/usr/
local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/kurier/sy-kurier.enc}{/usr/local/
texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/kurier/rm-kurier.enc}{/usr/local/texliv
e/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/kurier/mi-kurier.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2011
/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/nowacki/kurier/kurierl.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2011/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/nowacki/kurier/kurierli.pfb>
Output written on xavier.pdf (1 page, 35805 bytes).
Transcript written on xavier.log.
```

and they differ essentially only in the loaded languages.

`pdflatex` and `lualatex` (without `fontspec`) *don't* use OpenType fonts, but only Type1 fonts, with OMS, OML and OMX encoded fonts for math, relying on `.tfm` files for information about glyphs and extendable characters like parentheses. In this particular case, the Type1 fonts for OMS, OML, OMX and OT1 reside all in the two `.pfb` files `kurier.pfb` and `kurierli.pfb` and the various glyphs are selected via reencoding, as made clear by the loading of the files

```
ex-kurier.enc
sy-kurier.enc
rm-kurier.enc
mi-kurier.enc
```

The OpenType font Kurier Light *doesn't* have the math glyphs and the math tables that might make it be usable by `unicode-math`. Until their developer adds the support for Unicode Math, the OpenType Kurier font cannot be used as an argument for `\setmathfont` in a reliable way.

Comment: I don't think `pdflatex` has anything to do with the question, as from the start the question was on `OT` vs `T1` using `lualatex` (with or without `fontspec` resp.). But to the question, you basically say that the OpenType (OT) version of the font is missing glyphs that the Type 1 (T1) version has. If that is really the case, given the OT format can include T1 outlines, adding those glyphs from the T1 version to the OT version (without any additional typographic feature) should be trivial, no? I'll write to Janusz to check...

Comment: @Xavier I think that the comparison between the log files shows clearly what it's all about: LuaLaTeX uses the *very same* mechanism as pdflatex, when not loading `fontspec` (or, more precisely, the `luaotfload` mechanism).

Comment: I never questioned how `pdflatex` and `lualatex` worked, I know that rather well :)  My question is about Kurier OT vs T1. I've emailed Janusz to check if indeed the OT version of the Kurier font  is missing some glyphs compared to the T1 version, though I believe if it's missing something, it's rather embedded typographic features as the glyphs should be very easy to include.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind changing the syntax to that of the `scalerel` package, you can scale your parens

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Kurier Light Regular}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathit,\mathsfit]{Kurier Light Italic}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup,\mathbfsfup]{Kurier Bold}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit,\mathbfsfit]{Kurier Bold Italic}
\begin{document}
New:
\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} {\scaleleftright[0.8ex]{(}{1+\frac{1}{n}}{)}}^n \]

Original:
\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]
\end{document}
```

[image]