# Math kerning with non-math OpenType font

Tags: math-mode, kerning, opentype

I am setting my thesis in Garamond Premier Pro, which does not have support for OpenType math. Still, by mixing and matching, I have managed to hack together something usable, but sometimes the kerning in math mode is less than satisfactory.

I wonder if there is a way to globally fix this, i.e. not having to manually kern every instance. I do not think it is possible to add the pairs to the font's kerning table since the clash occurs between a roman delimiter and an italic letter. Furthermore, the delimiters are not even from Garamond, due to [unicode-math and braces scaling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52182).

MWEs:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,nabla=upright,partial=upright]{unicode-math}

\def\basemathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\def\myfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\def\mymathfont{\myfont}
\def\myboldfont{ Semibold}
\def\myitalicfont{ Italic}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
RawFeature={+calt,+onum},
ItalicFeatures={RawFeature={+calt,+dlig,+onum,+cswh,+swsh}}]{\myfont}

\let\amp\&
\renewcommand{\&}{{\fontspec{EB Garamond}\textit{\amp}}}

\setmathfont{\basemathfont}

\setmathfont[range={\mathup/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},\partial,
  \mathpunct,\mathbin,\mathrel,\infty,\mathpercent,\mathampersand,\mathdollar,\mathquestion},
CharacterVariant={5,11},Numbers=Lining]{\mymathfont}
\setmathfont[range={\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},\ell},
CharacterVariant={5,11},Numbers=Lining]{\mymathfont \myitalicfont}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},
CharacterVariant={5,11},Numbers=Lining]{\mymathfont \myboldfont}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},
CharacterVariant={5,11},Numbers=Lining]{\mymathfont \myboldfont \myitalicfont}


\setmathfont[range={\otimes,\oplus,\square,\boxtimes,\boxminus,\boxplus,\cdot,\nabla,\ll,\gg,\lll,\ggg,\mathcolon,\Rightarrow,\Longrightarrow,\Leftrightarrow,\Longleftrightarrow}]{\basemathfont}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathscr,\mathbfscr,
  "2AA1,"2AA2,"2AF7,"2AF8,\lesssim,\gtrsim,\in,\notin,
  \sumint,\equiv,\mp,\prime,\dprime,\trprime,\propto,\sim,\rightarrow,\leftarrow,\leftrightarrow,
  \dots,\ddots,\vdots,\parallel,\perp}]{XITS Math}

\AtBeginDocument{\Umathcode`\* = 0 0 "002A\relax}

% Blackboard bold from AMS math
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\protected\def\mathbb#1{{\mathchar\numexpr256*\symAMSb+`#1\relax}}

\begin{document}
$(j)$
$(f)$
$f(x)$
$[f]$
$\{f\}$
$\displaystyle\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f\right|_{x=4}$
\end{document}
```

which yields the following result:
[image: Failed math kerning, Garamond Premier Pro]
LuaLaTeX version:
[image: Failed math kerning, Garamond Premier Pro, LuaLaTeX version]

Similar results occur with EB Garamond

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,nabla=upright,partial=upright]{unicode-math}

\def\basemathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\def\myfont{EB Garamond}
\def\mymathfont{\myfont}
\def\myitalicfont{ 12 Italic}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
RawFeature={+calt,+onum},
ItalicFeatures={RawFeature={+calt,+dlig,+onum,+cswh,+swsh}}]{\myfont}

\let\amp\&
\renewcommand{\&}{{\fontspec{EB Garamond}\textit{\amp}}}

\setmathfont{\basemathfont}

\setmathfont[range={\mathup/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},\partial,\mathpunct,\mathbin,\mathrel,\infty,\mathpercent,\mathampersand,\mathdollar,\mathquestion},CharacterVariant={5,11},Numbers=Lining]{\mymathfont}
\setmathfont[range={\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},\ell},CharacterVariant={5,11},Numbers=Lining]{\mymathfont \myitalicfont}

\setmathfont[range={\otimes,\oplus,\square,\boxtimes,\boxminus,\boxplus,\cdot,\nabla,\ll,\gg,\lll,\ggg,\mathcolon,\Rightarrow,\Longrightarrow,\Leftrightarrow,\Longleftrightarrow}]{\basemathfont}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathscr,\mathbfscr,
  "2AA1,"2AA2,"2AF7,"2AF8,\lesssim,\gtrsim,\in,\notin,
  \sumint,\equiv,\mp,\prime,\dprime,\trprime,\propto,\sim,\rightarrow,\leftarrow,\leftrightarrow,
  \dots,\ddots,\vdots,\parallel,\perp}]{XITS Math}

\AtBeginDocument{\Umathcode`\* = 0 0 "002A\relax}

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\protected\def\mathbb#1{{\mathchar\numexpr256*\symAMSb+`#1\relax}}

\begin{document}
$(j)$
$(f)$
$f(x)$
$[f]$
$\{f\}$
$\displaystyle\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f\right|_{x=4}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Failed math kerning, EB Garamond]
LuaLaTeX version:
[image: Failed math kerning, EB Garamond, LuaLaTeX version]

EDIT: Added LuaLaTeX versions of the examples, per comments. For this to work, one has to add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` at the top and, in the case of Garamond Premier Pro, specify the font using the file names instead of the font names (this does *not* work with XeLaTeX though).

Comment: I don't get the same equal sign as in your picture from your second code sample. Is there some missing config in it? (asking before posting a possible approach in order to make sure I have right set-up).

Comment: You obviously don't have the newest luatex as you are not using luatex85, With it I get a quite different result, all the right delimiters are ok.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using XeLaTeX. I think I am not willing to switch to LuaTeX at this stage.

Comment: @jfbu No, there is nothing else than what I posted. I use the version of EB Garamond provided with Archlinux: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/otf-eb-garamond/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference you observe between XeTeX and LuaTeX is explained by the following excerpt from [mathastext's doc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext)

**edit** this excerpt being taken out of context, the first sentence is a bit ambiguous; it is to be read as "XeTeX may create italic corrections but it does *not* follow Appendix G of the TeXBook in their use in math mode, contrarily to LuaLaTeX". I have examined this further now (four years later) and report below on some interesting findings **also regarding pure text mode**.

> From brief testing on 2012/12/28, XeTeX seems not to create fake
>   italic corrections for OpenType fonts. Hence the TeX placement
>   algorithms for math mode described in this section do not work well
>   when an OpenType (text) font is used for the letters in math mode, and
>   the document is compiled with the XeTeX engine. On the other hand
>   LuaLaTeX seems to implement the italic corrections when using OpenType
>   fonts, but only with italic fonts (as far as I could tell). Try the
>   following (which will use the OpenType Latin Modern font) on a recent
>   TeX installation and compare the output of both engines:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{fontspec}
> \begin{document}
> \Huge
> $\mathit{f_i^i}$\par $\mathrm{f_i^i}$
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> Comment out the fontspec line and use pdfLaTeX. All three outputs are
>   different on my TeX installation. XeTeX does not have the italic
>   corrections. LuaLaTeX does, but only for the italic font. pdfLaTeX has
>   them for both the italic and the upright font.

---

I checked again about one year ago and nothing had changed. On your example I checked that the better spacing relative to the right delimiters is indeed explained by the insertion by LuaLaTeX of italic corrections.

---

Here is some additional experiment I did now about whether italic corrections are defined and whether they are used or not in math mode.

According to the TeXBook if the `\fontdimen2` parameter vanishes, then italic corrections should be used when letters follow one another. This is done by LuaLaTeX but not by XeTeX. Furthermore there is another problem that the italic corrections defined by XeTeX seem to differ from the ones defined by LuaLaTeX (**this shows also as a pure text mode difference**, cf the different widths of hboxes below `34.18512pt` vs  `35.18033pt` for `\hbox{f\/g\/k)}`).

Test document:

```
% Time-stamp: <03-11-2016 15:07:54 CET>

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\begin{document}

\Huge
% $\mathit{f_i^i} \mathit{(f\/)}$\par $\mathrm{f_i^i}$

\ifluatex
\usefont {EU2}{lmr}{m}{it}
\else
\usefont {EU1}{lmr}{m}{it}
\fi

\leavevmode\hbox{fgk}

\leavevmode\hbox{f\/g\/k}

\typeout{\the\fontdimen2\font}% 8.70801pt in both engines

$\mathit{fgk}$

\fontdimen2\font 0pt

$\mathit{fgk}$

\showoutput
\end{document}
```

Log with XeTeX:

```
....\hbox(17.51552+5.0755)x29.856
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 fgk
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.40898
...\hbox(17.51552+5.0755)x345.0, glue set 295.81488fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\hbox(17.51552+5.0755)x34.18512
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 f
.....\kern 3.63248
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 g
.....\kern 0.69664
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 k
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.40898
...\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x345.0, glue set 300.144fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\mathon
....\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x29.856
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 glyph#55
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 glyph#59
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 glyph#70
....\mathoff
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.40897
...\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x345.0, glue set 300.144fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\mathon
....\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x29.856
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 glyph#55
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 glyph#59
.....\EU1/lmr/m/it/24.88 glyph#70
....\mathoff
```

Log with LuaLaTeX:

nota bene: the `\kern1.59232` before the `\mathoff` (after having set to zero the `\fontdimen2` parameter) is the italic correction for the letter `k`. XeTeX puts no such italic correction and furthermore the value it assigns as italic correction for the `k` is  `1.09473pt` (in 24.88 point size) not the `1.59232pt` of LuaLaTeX.

(try with `\leavevmode\hbox{k\/}`

```
> 12.29073-1.09473;
                                   11.19600

> 12.78831-1.59232;
                                   11.19599
```

)

```
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
....\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x29.856, direction TLT
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 f
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 g
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 k
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.40897
...\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x345.0, glue set 294.81967fil, direction TLT
....\localpar
.....\localinterlinepenalty=0
.....\localbrokenpenalty=0
.....\localleftbox=null
.....\localrightbox=null
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
....\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x35.18033, direction TLT
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 f
.....\kern 4.13008
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 g
.....\kern 1.19424
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 k
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.40897
...\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x345.0, glue set 298.5517fil, direction TLT
....\localpar
.....\localinterlinepenalty=0
.....\localbrokenpenalty=0
.....\localleftbox=null
.....\localrightbox=null
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
....\mathon
....\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x31.44832, direction TLT
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 f
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 g
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 k
.....\kern1.59232
....\mathoff
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.40897
...\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x345.0, glue set 293.22736fil, direction TLT
....\localpar
.....\localinterlinepenalty=0
.....\localbrokenpenalty=0
.....\localleftbox=null
.....\localrightbox=null
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
....\mathon
....\hbox(17.51552+5.07552)x36.77264, direction TLT
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 f
.....\kern4.13008
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 g
.....\kern1.19424
.....\EU2/lmr/m/it/24.88 k
.....\kern1.59232
....\mathoff
```

---

The initial answer was edited to remove the action on operator names such as cos, sin, etc...

n.b.: mathastext (whose use is not recommended for OpenType fonts, but I am trying to use its rather sophisticated mechanism of math active letters here) has no official interface for different fonts for "upright" and "italic", the "italic" one (if used) being supposed to differ from the "upright" one only via the NFSS shape specifier  (usually "it" or "sl".) Here we use directly EB Garamond 12 Italic, but for mathastext it receives it from fontspec as an "upright" font, ie the NFSS shape specifier is "n". This is why operator names were also using the Italic font. Hence the edit reverts the corresponding action of mathastext on the font used for operator names.

A further side remark is that mathastext reserves two mathgroups. Here only one is actually needed, but there is no option to tell it to mathastext currently. In fact we could even make do without any additional mathgroup as the needed ones are already declared by unicode-math. But again, mathastext is primarily for pdftex use with traditional TeX fonts.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,nabla=upright,partial=upright]{unicode-math}

\def\basemathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\def\myfont{EB Garamond}
\def\mymathfont{\myfont}
\def\myitalicfont{ 12 Italic}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
RawFeature={+calt,+onum},
ItalicFeatures={RawFeature={+calt,+dlig,+onum,+cswh,+swsh}}]{\myfont}

\let\amp\&
\renewcommand{\&}{{\fontspec{EB Garamond}\textit{\amp}}}

\setmathfont{\basemathfont}

\setmathfont[range={\mathup/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},\partial,\mathpunct,\mathbin,\mathrel,\infty,\mathpercent,\mathampersand,\mathdollar,\mathquestion},CharacterVariant={5,11},Numbers=Lining]{\mymathfont}
\setmathfont[range={\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},\ell},CharacterVariant={5,11},Numbers=Lining]{\mymathfont \myitalicfont}

% load mathastext minimally
\makeatletter\let\operator@fontORI\operator@font\makeatother
\usepackage[basic, nodigits, nohbar, defaultimath,
            defaultalphabets, defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\makeatletter\let\operator@font\operator@fontORI\makeatother
% next line after looking in log file, there is surely better way, but I don't
% know if unicode-math has public interface for fetching the assigned
% NFSS font family name
\MTfamily{EBGaramond12Italic(0)}\Mathastext
%  Perhaps an alternative would be to to do
% skip the initial \setmainfont and issue instead
% \setmainfont[CharacterVariant={5,11},Numbers=Lining]{\mymathfont
% \myitalicfont}
% then:
% \usepackage[...]{mathastext}
% then:
% the correct \setmainfont.
%   but  I don't know how unicode-math interacts with the setmainfont setting
% 
% mathastext does not know that the font is "italic" (from the NFSS point of
% view it is defined with normal not italic shape) and it will thus try
% to insert "italic corrections" (cf documentation.) Get rid of that:
\MTnoicinmath
% Now we can use mathastext's facilities:
\MTsetmathskips{f}{5mu}{5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{j}{5mu}{3mu}
% Nota Bene: such skips are ignored inside inside \math... commands


\setmathfont[range={\otimes,\oplus,\square,\boxtimes,\boxminus,\boxplus,\cdot,\nabla,\ll,\gg,\lll,\ggg,\mathcolon,\Rightarrow,\Longrightarrow,\Leftrightarrow,\Longleftrightarrow}]{\basemathfont}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathscr,\mathbfscr,
  "2AA1,"2AA2,"2AF7,"2AF8,\lesssim,\gtrsim,\in,\notin,
  \sumint,\equiv,\mp,\prime,\dprime,\trprime,\propto,\sim,\rightarrow,\leftarrow,\leftrightarrow,
  \dots,\ddots,\vdots,\parallel,\perp}]{XITS Math}

\AtBeginDocument{\Umathcode`\* = 0 0 "002A\relax}

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\protected\def\mathbb#1{{\mathchar\numexpr256*\symAMSb+`#1\relax}}


\begin{document}
$(j)$
$(f)$
$[f]$
$\{f\}$
$\displaystyle\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f\right|_{x=4}$
\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

Produces on my TL2016:

[image]

You can adjust to your liking the extra skips on left and right of the letters via `\MTsetmathskips` as illustrated above only for `f` and `j`.

I tried with luatex (using `luatex85`), this is the result with your original code (everything `mathastext` related commented out), on my TL2016:

[image]

Notice how the two derivatives differ, the rendering in XeTeX is weird (see the "d" on top; this has nothing to do with use of `mathastext`, it gives the same without). And the fraction sign width seems to differ.

Another thing is that for some reason my equal sign is not like in your second picture. The one in my picture uses the EB Garamond from TeXLive.

---

A question about $ij$ was raised in a comment. I had forgotten about it but you can use the `\Mathnormal` defined by `mathastext`:  within it the extra skips configured via its command `\MTsetmathskips` are cancelled. Here is with the `\MTsetmathskips{j}{5mu}{3mu}` as above:

[image]

From input

```
\MTsetmathskips{j}{5mu}{3mu}

$ij, ijk$

$\Mathnormal{ij}, \Mathnormal{ijk}$

$i\Mathnormal{j}, i\Mathnormal{j}k$
```

The skips would also disappear inside `\mathnormal` but the latter, which is not modified by `mathastext` (cf its option `defaultalphabets`), is not configured to use the EB Garamond 12 Italic.

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks nice! I will give it a try. As you can see in my edit, I added the luatex versions as well.

Comment: Applying this to my whole thesis, I found one problem: all operator names (exp, sin, cos, &c.) are now italic. A smaller annoyance is that ij that was nicely kerned before, is too wide apart.

Comment: if really it is absolutely needed it is theoretically possibly for `i` which is "mathematically active" to examine the next token and if it is `j` do the appropriate thing. But we are stretching the limits of what is reasonable.