# Scaling of parentheses and brackets with unicode-math and kpfonts fails

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, scaling, braces, opentype

#### The problem

I use `unicode-math` and `lualatex` and for beamer presentations, I want a fully compatible OTF sans serif font (that looks good with Myriad Pro unlike GFSNeohellenicMath). Kp-Math-Sans works and isn't lacking any symbols like Fira-Math. Sadly, parentheses and right brackets can't be scaled up (not even with `\big`) although it works fine with Kp-Math-Regular.

Using `unicode-math`:

[image: With unicode-math]

Using `kp-fonts` (which loads the T1 font and does too much):

[image: With kp-fonts]

However, these two packages are incompatible with each other.

I also tried loading only ranges, but this only caused problems with scaling: Only Neohellenic (`\setmathfont[version=sf]{GFSNeohellenicMath}`):

[image: Neohellenic]

Both ( `\setmathfont[version=sf]{GFSNeohellenicMath} \setmathfont[ range={up, it, bb, frak, cal, scr, sfup, sfit, bfup,bfit, bfcal}, version=sf ]{KpMath-Sans}`):

[image: NeohellenicThenKpMathSans]

In this case everything was taken from KpMath-Sans (the pdf didn't contain NeoHellenic)

I also tried different combinations with Fira-Math but that even introduced division by 0 errors because the sizes of characters probably got messed up.

#### The question

Is there a way to combine fonts such that I can get correctly scaling braces? It would be extremely impractical to change all scaling braces to the proposed solution in this old related post: [unicode-math and braces scaling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52182/unicode-math-and-braces-scaling).

Also it seems that kp-math-Sans doesn't have the problem diagnosed there (not being a OTF-Math font).

Is there maybe a working version of the OTF file somewhere out there? Or can I load the T1 font in a way consistent with all the unicode-math stuff?

The minimal example from the pictures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nott, notext, notextcomp]{kpfonts}
% \usepackage{unicode-math}
% \setmathfont{Kp-Math-Regular}
% \setmathfont[version = sf]{KpMath-Sans}
\begin{document}
Normal:
$\left(\begin{matrix}
    ff\\gg\\gg\\hh
\end{matrix} \right)$ \quad
$\big(()\big)$ \quad
\mathversion{sf}
Sans Serif:
$\left[ \begin{matrix}
    ff\\gg\\gg\\hh
\end{matrix} \right]$ \quad 
$\left(\begin{matrix}
    ff\\gg\\gg\\hh
\end{matrix} \right)$ \quad
$\big(()\big)$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With LuaTeX or XeTeX you should use the OTF version of the kpfonts.

This works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Sans.otf}[version=sf]
\begin{document}
Normal:
$\left(\begin{matrix}
ff\\gg\\gg\\hh
\end{matrix} \right)$ \quad
$\big(()\big)$ \quad
\mathversion{sf}
Sans Serif:
$\left[ \begin{matrix}
ff\\gg\\gg\\hh
\end{matrix} \right]$ \quad
$\left(\begin{matrix}
ff\\gg\\gg\\hh
\end{matrix} \right)$ \quad
$\big(()\big)$
```

\end{document}

[image: PDF output]

Comment: Downloading the otf file from CTAN fixed it (it is 270 kB instead of 267 now). So maybe they fixed this issue since I first downloaded it.

Comment: Yes, the issue has been fixed recently in version 0.36 of the kpfonts-otf.